# precision and recall in recommendation systems

Tags: precision, precision-recall, recommendation-engine

I have designed a recommendation system and encountered a question in the evaluation process. In top 1 recommendation, both of precision and recall increase and in top 3 recommendation inversly increase. What is the reason for this? thank you.

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by inversely increase ?

Comment: for example: when precision increase, recall decrease

Comment: how are you calculating the precision and recall for top 3 recommendation. That will determine the trend, which you had explained